# Creacte Mysql Database copy

Tags: mysql

I need copy full database in MySql but cant to do this.

I try

```
mysqldump db_name | mysql new_db_name
```

Its work, but DB so big and this comand need 5Gb+ in max_allowed_packed
Maybe you know best solution?
Task: Full copy Database with data

Thanks!

Comment: So... it works. What is the problem with it? Is it too slow? Does it use too much memory? You can reset max_allowed_packets after the copy is complete.

Comment: Use Percona XtraBackup or Mariabackup for MariaDB instances

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways :

> **1 Backup & Restore :**

Take backup using mysqldump & restore backup with new name.

> **2 Manual Create Table in New Database :**

```
create schema new_schema;

select concat("create table new_schema.`",table_name,"` as select * from `",table_schema,"`.`",table_name,"`;")
from
information_schema.tables 
where table_schema='old_schema'; 

/* Execute the above statement output simultaneously*/

-- i.e
create table new_schema.`XXX` as select * from `njindiainvest`.`XXX`;
create table new_schema.`YYY` as select * from `njindiainvest`.`YYY`;
create table new_schema.`ZZZ` as select * from `njindiainvest`.`ZZZ`;
```